# MySQL Calculating the sum of each digit of an Text value

Tags: mysql

How to calculate the sum of each digit of an Text value in MySQL?

for example

```
SET @Chars = CONCAT('1','2','33'); 
-- @Chars = '1233' 

-- and result should be 1+2+3+3 = 9.
```

Comment: In my humble opinion, that shouldn't be the task of your SQL server to do that kind of things…

Comment: Thank you for opinion. Well I was making some changes on my db, and it's the part of the function that will validate it (just once). I need to calculate for one column if there are any invalid sums. It's not part of my application or DB system, it's just for check.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, not pretty to do, but here's a way to do it.  I'm like you -- had to do it for some spot checking.  We do check digit calculations and I needed some specific accounts where the digits would sum in various ways.

```
select (substring('123456', 1, 1) + 
    substring('123456', 2, 1) + 
    substring('123456', 3, 1) + 
    substring('123456', 4, 1) + 
    substring('123456', 5, 1) + 
    substring('123456', 6, 1) + 
    substring('123456', 7, 1) + 
    substring('123456', 8, 1) + 
    substring('123456', 9, 1) + 
    substring('123456', 10, 1) + 
    substring('123456', 11, 1) + 
    substring('123456', 12, 1)) as sumOfDigits;
```

So just replace '123456' with your string and then make sure that the 1..12 in this example is enough to cover the length of the max string you are expecting to calculate a total for.

Here's my real world example:

```
select (substring(a.member_number, 1, 1) + 
        substring(a.member_number, 2, 1) + 
        substring(a.member_number, 3, 1) + 
        substring(a.member_number, 4, 1) + 
        substring(a.member_number, 5, 1) + 
        substring(a.member_number, 6, 1) + 
        substring(a.member_number, 7, 1) + 
        substring(a.member_number, 8, 1) + 
        substring(a.member_number, 9, 1) + 
        substring(a.member_number, 10, 1) + 
        substring(a.member_number, 11, 1) + 
        substring(a.member_number, 12, 1)) as sumOfDigits,
a.member_number from account a
left join account a2 on a2.member_number = a.member_number and a2.discriminator = 'D'
where a.discriminator = 'S'
and a2.account_id is null having sumOfDigits = 16;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root there is very simple formula to do it.

In MySQL in can be specified this way:

```
@Chars - 9 * FLOOR( (@Chars-1 ) / 9 ).
```

Or any field / expression can be used instead @Chars.